# Firebase: deleting all the authenticated users

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am new to firebase and I wanted to create 10000 user with a script and I got blocked.

Now I want to delete them all and do it again but deleting it is a big problem now.

How can I delete all of these users? and make that 10000 users?

screenshot of random users I generated:
[image: screenshot]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to bulk delete users is likely through the Admin SDK which has an API to [list users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users), and then to [delete a user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user).

Comment: Thanks @Frank, how about creating user as much as I like? because I get `{code: "auth/too-many-requests", message: "We have blocked all requests from this device due to unusual activity. Try again later."}`

Comment: You also need to create the users using the admin SDK. You can use [importUsers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/import-users) for bulk user creation.

Answer (score 8):

Easier to do than you might think at first glance of the documentation.

A few lines will do it in Python:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import auth

cred = credentials.Certificate("/path/to/downloaded/json/key/*.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

for user in auth.list_users().iterate_all():
    print("Deleting user " + user.uid)
    auth.delete_user(user.uid)
```

Comment: For above code to work you would need to create a service account. Go in firebase project/settings/service account/ create new private key. Save that json on your machine and use that path above

Answer (score 0):

Since Node.js `firebase-admin` version `8.12.0`, [delete multiple users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_multiple_users) is supported.

Here is the sample code.

```
admin.auth().deleteUsers([uid1, uid2, uid3])
  .then(deleteUsersResult => {
    console.log('Successfully deleted ' + deleteUsersResult.successCount + ' users');
    console.log('Failed to delete ' +  deleteUsersResult.failureCount + ' users');
    deleteUsersResult.errors.forEach(err => {
      console.log(err.error.toJSON());
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('Error deleting users:', error);
  });
```

Notice: the maximum number of users allowed to be deleted is **1000** per batch like [list all users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users)

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can run the command from your shell using `firebase functions:shell`

---

If you have [gcloud sdk](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install) installed:

From your terminal

- login into firebase: `firebase login`
- create a folder and cd into it (or use your existing project)
  `mkdir sample_func && cd_$`
- initialize directory for firebase function

  - `firebase init functions`
  - follow prompts
- Write the code in `functions/index.js`.
  Something like this:

  ```
  const functions = require("firebase-functions");
  const admin = require("firebase-admin");

  admin.initializeApp();

  // Delete all users in firebase auth
  exports.deleteAllUsers = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
       const listUsers = await admin.auth().listUsers();
       for (const user of listUsers.users) {
           console.log(`Deleting user: ${user.email || 'anonymous'}`);
           await admin.auth().deleteUser(user.uid);

           // Wait to avoid hitting the rate limit. Note that this might cause
           // you function to timeout, in which case you might have to run the
           // functions multiple times. 
           await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 100));
       }
       res.send("All users deleted");
  });
  ```
- Run it locally.
  From within the folder:

  - `firebase functions:shell`
  - `deleteAllUsers()`